# wordpress4.8.2 Multilingual Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, multi-language

I have R&D on some plugin area where I have already created one plugin that works perfectly in multiple languages.

I'm use WordPress 4.8.2 and in that for plugin multi-language supported i have to add manually my plugin language folder's file into `wp-content/language/plugins/my-file-IN.po` and `wp-content/language/plugins/my-file-IN.mo`.

If I want that when I install/activate my plugin at that time is there anything using that I add my language folder's file in `wp-content/language/plugins/` folder directly?

for Ex. Here i want that if we change wordpress language default to Hindi all the things transfer in hindi but my plugin not work and if i put language in wp-content/language/plugins/ manually then it works

so is there anything like on plugin installation we add language in wp-content/language/plugins

Comment: in order to use directly the language files where are in your plugin directory, point out this directory with this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain

Comment: Hey @mmm Thanxx for comment Here language translated successfully but i have to add language file manually to the wp-content/language/plugin-name/... so i want the solution in that when i install plugin at that time language directory automatically copy to the wp-content/language/plugin-name/ location. so is there possible???

Comment: with the other function, you don't need to copy files, wordpress use files in your plugin directory

Comment: @mmm thnxx for faster reply, ok can you give me some demo for that how WordPress copy that file from my plugin directory or function name which perform this kind of job.

Comment: @mmm hello see i also use this link as a reference https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers